# display the very last td of tr in a table on new line within ng-repeat element

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, css

I have found quite a few similar questions but unfortunately none of them is doing the job for me and I am wondering how I can move very last td inside tbody of ng-repeat to the next line? Please consider my CSS skills are absolutely zero.

```
                        <table>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Column1</th>
                                <th>Column2</th>
                                <th>Column3</th>
                                <th>Column4</th>
                                <th>Column5</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody ng-repeat="items in ItemsList">
                            <tr ng-repeat="pItem in items.Items">
                                <td>{{pItem.Item1}}</td>
                                <td>{{pItem.Item2 }}</td>
                                <td>{{pItem.Items3 }}</td>
                                <td>{{pItem.Item4 }}</td>
                                <td>{{pItem.Item5 }}</td>
                                <td>{{pItem.Item6 }}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

pItem.Item6 is the column that I want to move to the next line (row with only one column spanned to the complete row size).

[image: I want Item6 to be on the next row]

I want Item6 to be at next row as follow.
[image]

Comment: well. your question is not very clear to me. can you draw in paint and put here?   But if you want to select particularly last td and do something then use $last in  ng-repeat .https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Comment: I have modified my question with the output I have at the moment and the result I want to get.

Comment: Why are you using `ng-repeat` in the `<tbody>` record? you should use it ONLY in the `<tr>`. Also, take a look at ` ng-if="$last"`. it allows you to set different behavior n the last repetition of `ng-repeat` (like changing the layout of the table record).

Comment: don't worry about that. It is due to of the complex nature of the data and also it is something passed on to me. ng-if="last" is only for the last item in the list while in my case I have to do it for each item in the list. I mean to move the last td of each item in the list to the new row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you want this

```html
<table>
    <tbody ng-repeat="items in ItemsList">
        <tr ng-repeat="pItem in items.Items">
            <td>
                <table>
                    <thead ng-if="$first && $parent.$first">
                       <tr>
                           <th>Column1</th>
                           <th>Column2</th>
                           <th>Column3</th>
                           <th>Column4</th>
                           <th>Column5</th>
                       </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{pItem.Item1}}</td>
                        <td>{{pItem.Item2 }}</td>
                        <td>{{pItem.Item3 }}</td>
                        <td>{{pItem.Item4 }}</td>
                        <td>{{pItem.Item5 }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="5">{{pItem.Item6 }}</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Tajkia, it is ok as long as there is only one row but for multiple rows it will create Item6 rows at the end of the table which is not right.

Comment: You are right. I have edited my post to add a `table` inside the `tr` of the outer table to print the columns consecutively. Can you test it now?

Comment: it is creating all the cells in very first column now

Comment: Can you make a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [plunker](https://plnkr.co/), so that I can see the output?

Comment: I have changed the table structure bit further and got it almost working. I have moved thead into the inner table inside tbody

Comment: i have posted the updated answer above. Can you please confirm me if that's the right approach?

Comment: This is excellent. It is working gr8 but there is another question. it will not  display the header when there is no data?

Comment: no, it will not, because it will not get inside the `ng-repeat` if there is no data.

Comment: but i want header to be displayed in all cases.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118019/discussion-between-tajkia-rahman-toma-and-learning-curve).

Comment: I have posted another [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38526777/1037569) to make it easier. You can check it.

Comment: I am marking your answer as it is close enough to the desired result. I have added a conditional table before this to show the header when there is no data.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <table>
    <tbody ng-repeat="items in ItemsList">
        <tr ng-repeat="pItem in items.Items">
            <td>
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Column1</th>
                            <th>Column2</th>
                            <th>Column3</th>
                            <th>Column4</th>
                            <th>Column5</th>
                       </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{pItem.Item1}}</td>
                            <td>{{pItem.Item2 }}</td>
                            <td>{{pItem.Items3 }}</td>
                            <td>{{pItem.Item4 }}</td>
                            <td>{{pItem.Item5 }}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="5">{{pItem.Item6 }}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

above i have moved the thead from outer table to the tbody of inner table and it is working now but header has started appearing for each and every row now

Comment: In your solution the `thead` will be repeated before each of the `tr` elements. I dont think want this. I have edited my answer to print the `thead` only once. Can you please check if that works.

Answer (score 0):

You can process the data in the controller to make the data structure as a flat array.

Inside the controller:

```
$scope.rows = [];

angular.forEach($scope.ItemsList, function(items){
    angular.forEach(items.Items, function(pItem){
        $scope.rows.push(pItem);
    });
});
```

And the html for this data structure would be:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column1</th>
            <th>Column2</th>
            <th>Column3</th>
            <th>Column4</th>
            <th>Column5</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody ng-repeat="row in rows">
        <tr>
            <td>{{row.Item1}}</td>
            <td>{{row.Item2 }}</td>
            <td>{{row.Item3 }}</td>
            <td>{{row.Item4 }}</td>
            <td>{{row.Item5 }}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5">{{row.Item6 }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```